# Jquery autopopulate not displaying

Tags: jquery-ui

Auto suggest is getting the response but unable to display properly. I ma tying to follow example at https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/ - this is working fine as I run as a separate project. But trying to implement same logic in my own project. It could be jquery-ui version issue ? Since the example using specific autosugget.min.js file.

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url(../css/bootstrap.min.css);     

</style>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$('#licenseNumber').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/invoiceNumberData.html',        
    minLength: 3,
    dataType: 'json',           
    delimiter: ",",     
   source: function(request,response) {
        $.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/secure/invoiceNumberData.html", request, response);
            console.log("response: " + response);                           
            
      $.map((response), function(item) {
                console.log("licenseNumber: " + item.licenseNumber);
              return { value: item.licenseNumber, data: item.id };            
       })               
     }          
 });
            


 });
 </script>
 
</head> 
  <body>        
    <main role="main" class="container" >   
    <input type="text"  id="licenseNumber" value="">
 </body>
  
</html>
```

[image: Results from server]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think my issue to get the data from json and assign to UI widget. Still working on it. Any help is appreciated.